# How to list the listUsers Cognito Identity Service provider?

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I have this code in which I have used the cognitoidentityserviceprovider Method known as listUsers which returns a list of all my cognito users. Below is the code.

```
createPatient = async () => {
    var params = { 
      UserPoolId: 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx', 
      AttributesToGet: [ "email" ],
      Filter: "",
      Limit: 10
   };

   var cognitoidentityserviceprovider = new AWS.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider();
      cognitoidentityserviceprovider.listUsers(params, function(err, data) {
        if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
        else     console.log(data);         // successful response
      })
}
```

Now on one hand I would like to know how I can return the result in e.g a `<div></div>` like when one returns the values of a listquery when dealing with graphql queries.

On the other hand I would like to know how I could create form which takes in the data (UserpoolId, AttributesToGet, Filter, Limit) and maps the values to params so that e.g a user could fill them out himself.

Hope I have expressed myself well. Thanks a lot for any help.

Comment: I would need more information in order to help you out. You get a JSON output after the ListUsers API call. You would like to format that, and keep it in between <div> tags? If that is the case, you could format it just the way you would do with any other JSON data.

Comment: yeah but I can't figure out how to format it, could you maybe show me an example using the code I provided if you are chanced? Also hope L deosn't comearound for ya lol